# How to change child click event to parent div in angular2/4

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

am working on tile base interface design using angular2,Tile name and image click events are  fetching details from db.Now iam trying to fetch details when click on article div.please check my code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemdetails;">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">             
<article class="col-item">
<figure class="photo">                    
<a [routerLink]="['/productdetails',item.ItemID]">                           
<img [src]="item.ItemImage1" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Product Image" />
</a>
</figure>
<div class="info">
<div class="row" style="margin:0px;">
<div class="ItemDetails ellipseArea">                         
<a [routerLink]="['/productdetails',item.ItemID]">
<span class="Subtext">{{item.ItemDescription}}</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</article>
</div> <!--col ends-->
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Could you provide some information on the specific issue you are facing with your problem? Is your click event not firing - are you seeing any error messages. Narrowing it down would help your question get some better answers..

Comment: @ Anton v B  thx for your replay. actually the above code is working perfectly with a tag click event. what iam trying is to change that click event to the whole div(click event for article div) please send me a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

template

```
<article class="col-item" (click)="fetchDetails(item)">
```

component

```
fetchDetails( _item ) {
    this._http.(...)
}
```

Comment: thx for your reply  <a [routerLink]="['/productdetails',item.ItemID]"><article></article> </a> . is that possible like this?

Comment: It is, but then you are not "fetching data" per say, but you are also navigation to a different link :). Otherwise, it's fine.